# ASP.NET MVC3 using Redirect To Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use the Redirect to Action result on this code which gives a null but i have several if statements and the code is becoming more complex to build need a solution on how i could use the Redirect to Action which outputs null, help please?

```
   public ActionResult Convert(double temperature, string convertTo)
    {
        ViewBag.Temperature = temperature;
        ViewBag.ConvertTo = convertTo;


        if (convertTo.Equals("Celsius"))
        { ViewBag.ConvertedTemperature = this.FahrenheitToCelsius(temperature); }

        else

            { ViewBag.ConvertedTemperature = this.CelsiusToFahrenheit(temperature); }
            return View("Convert");
    }
```

Comment: ehh? Redirect where and how?

Comment: Your question really isnt very clear at the moment, where are you trying to redirect too?

Answer (score 1):

The error message would really help. But it seems like you'd need to make your temperature parameter nullable, like so:

```
public ActionResult Convert(double? temperature, string convertTo)
```

Then you could check for null and return RedirectToAction:

```
if (temperature == null)
    return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

You'll also need to do the following to get the temperature value in your conversion methods:

```
temperature.Value
```

Hope this helps.